# Android: invalid parent reference

Tags: java, android, xml

Things get weird when I using Android Studio 3.0 to open a project which was programmed under Android Studio in an older version, after `sync`, this piece of code didn't work which was programmed by my friend, but I just can't figure it out that why it doesn't work.

```
 <style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle"
    parent="style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorLightPurple</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

This is the screenshot of the error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It must be `@style`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

change `parent="style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"` to 
`parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"`